# Issue in Mapping of Tables using annotations in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

From so many days,I am stuck in mapping of tables in Hibernate using annotations.But i am not able to solve or find what is issue in my code. I am using criteria HQl Query to fetch Datas by creating Entities by annotations.
 Below is shown how the tables are built.

Below is mapping Tables
[image]

PK - Primary Key, with Not null and Auto Increment
FK - Foreign Key, with Not null

SQL Dta Sample[image]

Here each question_id has multiple options(answers i.e answer_id) and each answer_id has answer_text in 2 languges. Each question_id has question_text in 2 languages. questions are divided between 4 subjects.

Subject.java

```
 @Entity  
@Table(name = "SUBJECT")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Subject {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_ID")  
    private Long        subjectId;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_NAME")
    private String      subjectName;
```

Question.Java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "QUESTION")

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Question {
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")  
    private Long        questionId;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")
    private String      answerId;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_ID")
    private Long    subjectId;

    @Column(name = "QUESTION_TEST_TYPE")
    private String questionTestType;

    @Column(name = "BATCH_ID")
    private Long batchId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="question")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<QuestionText> questionTexts = new HashSet<QuestionText>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="question")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<Answer>(0);
```

Answer.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "ANSWER")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Answer {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")  
    private Long  answerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name="QUESTION_ID",nullable=false)
    private Question question;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="answer")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<AnswerText> answerText = new HashSet<AnswerText>(0);
```

QuestionText.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "QUESTIONTEXT")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)



  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class QuestionText {

        @Id  
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "QUESTION_TEXT_ID")  
        private Long        questionTextId;

        @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
        private Long        questionId;

        @Column(name = "QUESTION_TEXT")
        private String      questionText;

@ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name="LANGUAGE_ID",nullable=false)
    private Language language;


    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name="QUESTION_ID",nullable=false)
    private Question question;
```

AnswerText.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "ANSWERTEXT")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AnswerText {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT_ID")  
    private Long answerTextId;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)  
    private Long answerId;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT")  
    private String answerText;

    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name="LANGUAGE_ID",nullable=false)
    private Language language;

    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name="ANSWER_ID",nullable=false)
    private Answer answer;
```

Language.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "LANGUAGE")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Language {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")  
    private Long        languageId;

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_CODE")
    private String      languageCode;

    @Column(name = "TERRITORY")
    private String      territory;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="language")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<AnswerText> answerText = new HashSet<AnswerText>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="language")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<QuestionText> questionText = new HashSet<QuestionText>();
```

Issues facing is:

1.) I have 2 languages in my DB,issue is **I get english lang questions for Spanish Answers and Vice versa or some time shows spanish instead of english**. But in DB i have english questions for english answers and Spanish Quesions for Spanish answers only.

Here are questions:

1.)In quesitonText Table i have not set question_id as FK, does that effect mapping.

2.)In Question Table, batch_id is PK of some Other table, Should i set that as FK? Here batch_id can be Null. Does this effect any Mapping?

Can any body point out what is going wrong in my code. so it displays mix of spanish and english. PLease help me on this.Please

Comment: Is it questionText and answerText in the Language entity that show mix of spanish and english?

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your setup, but I was expecting `QuestionText` to contain

```
@ManyToOne
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinColumn(name="LANGUAGE_ID",nullable=false)
private Language language;
```

You even have this in `Language`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="language")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Set<QuestionText> questionText = new HashSet<QuestionText>();
```

If you could post an SQL that correctly gets all the questions and answers for a specific language, it will be helpful to understand how your database is structured.

Some other thoughts on your ER diagram:
Why does question table have reference to answer_id when answer table has reference to question_id? You can possibly remove the answer_id field in question table...?

Comment: Edit code please refer. Question Table contains answer_id of correct answer to that question. and added sql sample Data. Please help me on this

Comment: Ok, then I understand :) Where/how do you see the mix of english and spanish questions and answers - where you shouldn't see? How do you specify the language to get e.g. only english questions?